# Unable to reassign values in a linq statement

Tags: c#, linq

I'm attempting to square all the numbers in a list of type int. However when I run the code the list appears not to be changed at all.

```
public static List<int> SquareList(List<int> root)
{
    root.ForEach(x => x = x*x);
    return root;
}
```

Test class in x_unit.

```
[Fact]
public void testSqures()
{
    var input = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
    var expected = new List<int> { 1, 4, 9 };
    var result = Square.SquareList(input);

    Assert.Equal(expected,result);
}
```

Question does the `foreach` operator not change the underlying object?

Do I need to create a new list? or is there a way to transform the list in place?

Comment: From MSDN: Modifying the underlying collection in the body of the `Action<T>` delegate is not supported and causes undefined behavior.

Comment: you are working with a value type and the value type can not be updated in the `Action` delegate. You will definitely need to create a new list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to

```
return root.Select(x => x*x).ToList();
```

This does not alter the existing list, it creates a new list and returns it which would be preferred. If you really want to update the original list change the signature to pass in a `ref` and then update the pointer to the new list.

```
public static List<int> SquareList(ref List<int> root)
{
    root = root.Select(x => x*x).ToList();
    return root;
}
```

or use it with a for loop

```
public static List<int> SquareList(List<int> root)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < root.Count; i++)
        root[i] = root[i]*root[i];
    return root;
}
```

`ForEach` does iterate over the list and if you had a reference type (class) that contained an `int` you could change the value inside of that type but you cant reassign the pointer contained in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Use Select instead of ForEach if you want to get new representation of collection. Returning new object instead of changing it is a paradigm of functional programming. And LINQ helps to use this paradigm.

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN:

> Modifying the underlying collection in the body of the Action delegate is not supported and causes undefined behavior.

You should just use a regular `for` loop to do such things, instead of LINQ or similar functional statement

```
public static List<int> SquareList(List<int> root)
{
    for (int i = 0, n = root.Count; i < n; ++i)
        root[i] = root[i] * root[i];
    return root;
}
```

Comment: The documentation you cite has nothing to do with the question. The warning refers to modification of the structure of the collection, i.e. removal or insertion/addition of elements, not simple replacement of values.

Comment: @PeterDuniho With all due respect, do you have any official documentation or code example with ValueType to prove your point? I think you are confused between the terms `Modifying the underlying collection` with `Modifying the values referred to by the underlying collection`

Comment: If you attempt to modify the collection, an `InvalidOperationException` is thrown, with the message _"Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute."_. This is a completely different issue than attempting to modify a value type that itself is not actually part of the collection. Code example: `List<int> values = new List<int> { 0, 1, 2 }; values.ForEach(i => values[i] = i + 1);`, throws an exception. It's correct  that `ForEach()` shouldn't be used to modify the list, but it is incorrect to cite that particular section of the documentation, as it's irrelevant to the OP's code.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Your code example supports what I am saying. No one here seems to be talking about `attempting to modify a value type that itself is not actually part of the collection`. `List<int>` is a reference type and `int` is a value type and we are talking of modifying this contained `int` (value type) within the container `List<int>` (reference type). I don't have any further comments to make on this subject

Comment: The OP is replacing the value stored in `x` passed to his `Action<int>` delegate with `x*x`. This has no effect on the original collection, and thus the warning in MSDN does not apply.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Try to understand this: If it worked, there would have been no question on this forum by the OP. All the answers attempt to to explain why the `ForEach` does not work, why they (Microsoft) don't provide another variation which you can use to modify the values in the `List`, and what are the OPs alternatives